# How to access nullable typescript nested type

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror, tslint, typescript-eslint

I want to extract a nested type like in the code below. Is there a way to do that for a nullable field?

```
type Query = { a: { b?: { c: string } };

type c = Query['a']['b']['c'];

Property 'c' does not exist on type '{ c: string; } | undefined'.ts(2339)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type Query = { a: { b?: { c: string } } };

type foo = NonNullable<Query['a']['b']>['c'];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrhATiKBeKBvKBDAXJqAIwH58sBjfAZ2EQEsA7AcygF822BuAKG9EigAzAPbC0UAHLCGEuABs52QnIgAeeEhABtAOTYdAXV2FDAPl3lDnIA)